# Does achieving a higher combo in Hydrophobia means getting more points?

Tags: hydrophobia

The questions sounds silly, but it begs to be asked. When I blow up a small explosive container, I get a red notification saying: 100 points. I blow up two that are close together with the same shot and get "200." I blow up four and get "400."

Is that 100, 200, 400 per container, or total? Does combo actually let you get higher scores?